# How can i parse a JSON String prefixed with the character 'u'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a JSON string that i am trying to parse:

```
[{u'OrderItem': {u'OrderItemId': u'123456789', u'Title': u'Product Title', u'QuantityShipped': u'0', u'IsTransparency': u'false', u'QuantityOrdered': u'1', u'ItemTax': {u'CurrencyCode': u'USD', u'Amount': u'0.00'}, u'ASIN': u'123456789', u'SellerSKU': u'BBB-123456789', u'ConditionSubtypeId': u'New', u'ConditionId': u'New', u'PromotionDiscountTax': {u'CurrencyCode': u'USD', u'Amount': u'0.00'}, u'TaxCollection': {u'Model': u'MarketplaceFacilitator', u'ResponsibleParty': u'Random Services, Inc.'}, u'PromotionDiscount': {u'CurrencyCode': u'USD', u'Amount': u'0.00'}, u'ItemPrice': {u'CurrencyCode': u'USD', u'Amount': u'100.35'}, u'ProductInfo': {u'NumberOfItems': u'1'}, u'IsGift': u'false'}}]
```

I'm not sure why but every part of the JSON is prefixed with the letter 'u' and i am not sure what i can do to parse this.

I read online that in python this is normal but in rails i just get an error, is there any way to parse this into JSON?

Comment: Maybe remove the u first, and then parse?

Comment: @sam i was thinking of doing that with a gsub but that feels like a bad solution, if for any reason any of the contents of the json includes u' it would get replaced

Comment: Removing the `u`s still wont result in valid JSON. JSON doesn't allow single quotes. Where are you getting this data from?

Comment: @3limin4t0r webhook from Zappier thats sending Amazon order data. Just tested and noticed that it is in fact not valid JSON like you said.

Comment: I was able to convert this specific example with `data['OrderItems'].gsub("u'", "'").gsub("'",'"')` i don't think it's the best solution but i will wait to see if i get any more input

Comment: @ricks I would say you should gsub `{u'` and `\su'` (whitespace + `u`), because otherwise if a string ends with `u` it will remove it. If the document doesn't have double quotes than I think the approach I've described is safe, because `'` will never appear _inside a string_, it would need to be escaped `\'`

Comment: @maxpleaner Makes sense Max, thats a good solution. If you'd like submit it as the answer.

Comment: `.gsub("'",'"')` is a bit risky though. What if the string contains the `"` character?

Comment: A better question is why you're getting garbage to begin with.

Comment: Can the data provided by the the webhook not be configured?

Comment: This isn't JSON, it's some custom serialization format that looks vaguely like JSON

Comment: @max i sent their support the same question

Comment: @3limin4t0r this is the return value for that specific field, while i wait to get approved for an amazon api access this is all i can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If possible I'd check if the data provided by the webhook can be configured into proper JSON.** If not I would let Python transform the string to JSON, since you say this is readable there.

I've no experience using Python, so there might be a better way of doing this, but something like this would do the trick:

```py
# to_json.py
import sys
import ast
import json

input  = sys.stdin.read().strip()
output = ''

if input:
    object = ast.literal_eval(input)
    output = json.dumps(object)

print(output)
```

Now in Ruby you can do the following:

```
require 'json' # not needed in Rails

string = "[{u'OrderItem': {u'OrderItemId': u'123456789', u'Title': u'Product Title', u'QuantityShipped': u'0', u'IsTransparency': u'false', u'QuantityOrdered': u'1', u'ItemTax': {u'CurrencyCode': u'USD', u'Amount': u'0.00'}, u'ASIN': u'123456789', u'SellerSKU': u'BBB-123456789', u'ConditionSubtypeId': u'New', u'ConditionId': u'New', u'PromotionDiscountTax': {u'CurrencyCode': u'USD', u'Amount': u'0.00'}, u'TaxCollection': {u'Model': u'MarketplaceFacilitator', u'ResponsibleParty': u'Random Services, Inc.'}, u'PromotionDiscount': {u'CurrencyCode': u'USD', u'Amount': u'0.00'}, u'ItemPrice': {u'CurrencyCode': u'USD', u'Amount': u'100.35'}, u'ProductInfo': {u'NumberOfItems': u'1'}, u'IsGift': u'false'}}]"

json = IO.popen('python to_json.py', 'r+') do |io|
  io.puts(string)
  io.close_write # closing write sends EOF, signalling the end of input
  io.read
end

JSON.parse(json)
#=> [{"OrderItem"=>{"ASIN"=>"123456789", "ConditionId"=>"New", "OrderItemId"=>"123456789", "Title"=>"Product Title", "IsGift"=>"false", "ConditionSubtypeId"=>"New", "SellerSKU"=>"BBB-123456789", "PromotionDiscountTax"=>{"CurrencyCode"=>"USD", "Amount"=>"0.00"}, "TaxCollection"=>{"Model"=>"MarketplaceFacilitator", "ResponsibleParty"=>"Random Services, Inc."}, "PromotionDiscount"=>{"CurrencyCode"=>"USD", "Amount"=>"0.00"}, "ItemPrice"=>{"CurrencyCode"=>"USD", "Amount"=>"100.35"}, "ProductInfo"=>{"NumberOfItems"=>"1"}, "QuantityShipped"=>"0", "IsTransparency"=>"false", "QuantityOrdered"=>"1", "ItemTax"=>{"CurrencyCode"=>"USD", "Amount"=>"0.00"}}}]
```

**Note:** This assumes you have Python installed on your machine and you've put the Python script in the same working directory as the Ruby script.

Python references:

- [`sys.stdin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)
- [`io.TextIOBase.read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.read)
- [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)
- [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)
- [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps)
- [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print)

Ruby references:

- [`IO::popen`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-c-popen)
- [`IO#puts`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-i-puts)
- [`IO#close_write`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-i-close_write)
- [`IO#read`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/IO.html#method-i-read)
- [`JSON#parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse)

Answer (score 0):

Don't adapt. Make the source fix their output.

Really.

Comment: I reached out to them (Zappier) but it doesn't seem like they're gonna fix it. I applied to get access to the Amazon Seller API so i have to use Zappier as an alternative until i get approved and i don't have to deal with this.